# What is the story of Lord Vishnu slaying the demon Jambha?

Tags: vishnu, reference-request, asuras, demon

[This chapter](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03102.htm) of Mahabharata describes the Devas eulogizing Lord Vishnu as he slew the demon called Jambha:-

> O lord, it was by thee that that wicked Asura, Jambha by name, who was a mighty bowman and who always obstructed sacrifices, was slain.

But, what is the story about Lord Vishnu killing Jambha? Do any other scriptures mention it?

Comment: I think it's just a random mention; there've been a number of slain Jambhas throughout the canon. See this [entry](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/jambha). Same [Jambha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc493067.html) is here.

Comment: @CDR I knew that Vishnu and Indra are desirous to kill Jambha. But, that means Krishna and Arjuna are desirous to slay Jayadratha (possibly he was the reincarnation of Jambha).

Answer (score 0):

There are many instances of demons named Jambha being slain by gods like Vishnu, Krishna, and Indra. As I wrote in a comment, I am pretty sure that this is a random mention, and since there are so many examples, it's hard to know which one is being referred to. My *guess* is that the specific battle may be the one detailed in [Skanda Purana 4.20](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627259.html), though there's no mention of this Jambha being a great bowman:

> 49. With their eyes blood-shot with anger the best and the pre-eminent demons like Baka, Yajñakopa, Brahmaghna, Vedadūṣaka, Mahāmakhaghna, **Jambha**, Rāhu and Vakraśira as well as other demons then began to strike at Janārdana [Vishnu] to tear him apart into pieces.
> 50. Then getting enraged both Janārdana and Saṃkarṣaṇa began to strike the strong demons with their respective discus and plough.

That is the most specific story I can find.

Comment: Those Asuras got destroyed lol.